# Get archived versions from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-java

How do I get a list of [archived versions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning#_ListingObject) of a file via `gcloud-java`? I don't see an option in [`Bucket.list()`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.1.4/apidocs/com/google/gcloud/storage/Bucket.html#list(com.google.gcloud.storage.Storage.BlobListOption...)), is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 1):

If version is enabled for the bucket then listing should return all the available versions (BlobId includes the version). Do you experience a different behavior?

Comment: `Bucket.list()`, by default, returns archived versions? That seems confusing. I'll double-check, but I don't *think* that was the behavior I was seeing.

Comment: Including all versions in listing is enabled by [default](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list). It looks like BlobListOptions is missing a way to change it. I created this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/issues/687) to fix that.

Comment: Actually I think you are right. I think I read the comment "lists all versions of an object as distinct results" backwards (focusing on the **distinct** part). In any case, we should be able to resolve the issue soon and support a way to specify it.

Comment: Thanks, you [beat me to the punch](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/issues/687) :)